# Sort a mysql table, drop it and create new one sorted

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following structure:

country, city, population

The table is alphabetically sorted by city,
I want to sort by population desc and create a new table that is sorted this way.

What would be the query to be used in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use  SELECT with ORDER BY?

Comment: Tables are not inherently sorted. The order in which rows are retrieved from tables is, formally, unpredictable, unless you include an `ORDER BY` clause in your query. Anytime you run a query without `ORDER BY` and the rows come back in some order that seems to be correct, that's luck, not design.

Comment: it struggles when applying the order by because of too many records, order by primary on the new table will do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the desired result using a single query:

`Create table new_table  select * from table order by population desc;`

Comment: +1 I knew that "create table ... select" worked on PostgreSQL, didn't knew it works in mysql to. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you would need to do this when you can just:

```
select country, city, population from table order by population desc;
```

To answer you question:

```
create table new_table like table;
insert into new_table select * from table order by population desc;
```

Comment: It takes 10 seconds to sort by population, whereas if there is no sort applied the results come in a second sorted alphabetically as on the database. I can't get past 10% of the database from the error log before it hangs up, there are over 3 million records to be sorted, is there a way of doing it in sessions?

Comment: Could it be possibly done somehow by selecting first the results with a population > 0 as most have population = to zero then do insert of results in which population is 0, first > 0 , then equal to 0, how would the query go? thank you

Comment: Check your indexes first, a lot of times it's faster to add an index to a table than select from it without one, event is you drop the table after. An why it matters if it's slower, I guess you only do this once, arent you ? I can't give you better advice because I don't realy understand what are you trying to achive.